# How to register the event in $scope using handlebar in twitter typeahead

Tags: angularjs, twitter-typeahead

I am using the latest twitter typeahead using custom templates using AngularJS.

I am able to get the desired output but I have a button in the custom templates that appears when we enter anything in the dropdown.

[image]

Here is the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/u5zkXhry0bCu6u5r0WuP?p=preview

Now when I click on the Add button the event is not getting fired. I think the event is not getting registered in the $scope. How can I do this over here ?

```
$('#prependedInput').typeahead({
            hint: true,
            highlighter: function (x) { return x; },
            minLength: 3,
        },
        {
            name: 'members',
            displayKey: 'value',
            source: getUserSearchData,
            templates: {
                suggestion: Handlebars.compile('{{member}}')
            }
        });

        Handlebars.registerHelper('member', function (items) {
            var item = this;
            var items = '<li><a><div class="row"><img style="height: 40px; float:left" src=' + getAvatarUrl(item) + ' /><span style="padding: 0.5em; float:left;"> ' + getDisplayName(item) + '</span><button class="btn btn-sm pull-right" ng-click="confirmAddDialog(' + item.id + ')">Add</button></div></a></li>';
            return new Handlebars.SafeString(items)
        });
```

I do have one function to fire a modal popup.

```
$scope.confirmAddDialog = function (userId) {
            flashSvc.add('we are hit...');

        };
```

How can I register the event using template.

Comment: please setup a plunk.

Comment: here is the plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/u5zkXhry0bCu6u5r0WuP?p=preview